# Avoid creating 'new' String objects when converting a byte[] to String using a specific charset

Tags: java, string, character-encoding, pool

I'm reading from a binary file and want to convert the bytes to US ASCII strings. Is there any way to do this without calling `new` on `String` to avoid multiple semantically equal `String` objects being created in the string literal pool? I'm thinking that it is probably not possible since introducing `String` objects using double quotes is not possible here. Is this correct?

```
private String nextString(DataInputStream dis, int size)
throws IOException
{
  byte[] bytesHolder = new byte[size];
  dis.read(bytesHolder);
  return new String(bytesHolder, Charset.forName("US-ASCII")).trim();
```

Comment: There is no "normal object pool." What are you talking about?

Comment: @erickson: I meant the JVM's heap vs the String literal pool.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd have to have a cache mapping byte arrays to strings, then search through the cache for any equal values before creating a new string.

You can intern existing strings with `intern()` as Yishai posted - that won't stop you from *creating* more strings, but it'll make all but the first one (for any char sequence) very short lived. On the other hand, it'll make all the distinct strings live for a very long time indeed.

You can have "pseudo-interning" by using a `Map<String, String>`:

```
String tmp = new String(bytesHolder, Charset.forName("US-ASCII")).trim();
String cached = cache.get(tmp);
if (cached == null)
{
    cached = tmp;
    cache.put(tmp, tmp);
}
return cached;
```

You could even put a bit more effort in and end up with an LRU cache so that it'll keep the N most recently fetched strings, discarding others when it needs to.

None of that reduces the number of strings created in the first place, as I say - but is that likely to be a problem in your situation? GCs have been tuned to make it very cheap to create short-lived objects.

Comment: It's not a problem to have 'new' called if they will be garbage collected, I was more concerned with the number of Strings in the pool. But you are right when saying they may be too 'long lived' using intern(). Something to think about.

Answer (score 3):

You can call the intern() method on the string to ensure one for the whole JVM.

```
String s = new String(bytes, "US-ASCII").intern();
```

You won't avoid creating the initial string again, but you will save on the storage.

That being said, interned strings have a limited storage space, so use with caution. A better option may be to implement a HashMap with the string as the key and value and check if the string already exists and get it if it does, insert it if it doesn't. That way you won't have such memory limitations.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know about intern(). I'll go check out interning and decide whether it's worth it or not.

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn’t be concerned about it—unless you profiled your application and have determined the `String` creation to be the exact source of your problem.

If you find out that the `String` creation *is* the source of your problem I would recommend what [Jon Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1578417/avoid-creating-new-string-objects-when-converting-a-byte-to-string-using-a-sp/1578443#1578443) proposed, i.e. a mapping from `byte[]` to `String`. That has about the same effect as [interning](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#intern()) your `String`s while not hogging up valuable memory until you restart the VM.